# Find if a node is reachable using BFS

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am using BFS to check if a node is reachable and for printing the route.
Can anyone explain why BFS is preferred over DFS in this case?
Using below code:

```
    LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    HashSet<String> visitedNodes = new LinkedHashSet<String> ();
    queue.add(source);
    visitedNodes.add(source);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        String focusNode = queue.poll();
        Set<Node> nodeSet = inputMap.getAllOutgoingNodes(focusNode);
        if (null != nodeSet) {
            for (Node s: nodeSet) {
                if (!visitedNodes.contains(s.edge1)) {
                    visitedNodes.add(s.edge1);
                    queue.add(s.edge1);
                    if (destination.equals(s.edge1)) {
                        for (String sn: visitedNodes) {
                            System.out.print(sn);     
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Preferred --> opinion-based. IMO there is no advantage on average, so the reasons if any would mostly be opinion-based. (avoid stack overflow, easier to code, don't have to move to a function, etc etc)

Comment: " why BFS is preferred over DFS in this case?"  what is this claim based upon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is to check if a node is reachable then I believe a DFS is preferred (usually just for length of code), if you also have to find a route then the one found with a DFS might be very long (and so very difficult for a human to check), therefore a BFS is preferred.

But anyway there are no general rules, it is all down to personal preference.